# Visual Studio 2010 - Is it slow for anyone else?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, performance

I've read a lot of stuff about VS2010 being much more performant than VS2008.  When I've finally installed it, I found that it, in fact, is much slower (save for the Add References dialog).

For instance, Silverlight projects take twice as long to load, the startup of the IDE itself is much slower, etc...

Am I missing something here or is it like this for everyone?

Specs: WinXP-32bit, 3.5GB RAM, 7200RPM drive, NVIDIA QUadro NVS 285 128MB, Cure2Duo E4400 @ 2GHz, PAE enabled.

Comment: Only 128 MB of VRAM?  Quadros aren't exactly optimized for desktop work either, I understand they have great OpenGL drivers which is important for CAD, but VS2010 uses the Microsoft stack (Direct2D actually, but it depends on driver Direct3D acceleration), not OpenGL.  Also, I don't think Direct2D benefits from ANY hardware acceleration on XP.  Can you give it a try with Win7?

Comment: Ben: You're not seriously suggesting that displaying the text and rectangles on the UI is what's slowing down VS, are you?

Comment: @Gabe: I agree with Ben.  From experience, Visual Studio doesn't like video cards with low amounts of ram.  And with the UI engine change, VS2010 wants at least a mid-range card.  When 2005 shipped we had issues with just viewing the design surface on some html pages.  After adding a $50 card with a decent amount of ram VS2005 became much more responsive.  Pages that took 60+ seconds to display started showing up immediately.

Comment: I'm not saying that a better video card won't help, but it sure won't make Silverlight projects load faster.

Comment: @Gabe: Silverlight is hardware accelerated.  Of course a better video card would improve performance of not just the silverlight application but especially the ability to develop that application.

Comment: Silverlight uses hardware acceleration only for media playback. Regardless, the Silverlight runtime isn't even invoked when loading a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, I've found it sluggish for a number of things, vs2008 seems snappier except for the add references :)

Answer (score 9):

Try disabling, the hardware acceleration for WPF and let WPF render on software.
This setting has helped me to load VS with my project almost 200% faster even after machine boot. 
This also helped me to get rid of the Splash screen at the beginning of VS 2010 start.

Go to Tools | Options, then select Environment | General.  Then uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience..." and "Use hardware graphics acceleration..."

[image]
One more tip.
Try forcing the garbage collection for the IDE by using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F12.
I have found this to be helpful....

This will be very helpful if you are flipping between lot of projects and also if you have lot of IDE's open for different projects.

And lastly if you have any extensions, try disabling the ones that are not used all times.
Disabling **codemaid** helped me save a lot of time while typing and switching between code pages.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the Windows Automation API 3.0 can help some people:

> Visual Studio 2010 runs faster when the Windows Automation API 3.0 is
>   installed
>
> -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981741

*Windows Automation API 3.0 is included in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2* 
-- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976779

Comment: It's installed.  Don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Updated answer with this info: *Windows Automation API 3.0 is included in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2* -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976779

Answer (score 4):

"Did you just get a new computer without telling me.."

**NO - I just deleted my breakpoints!**

Over the course of a year you may accumulate hundreds of break points. Considering it just took me several minutes to delete all the breakpoints I had I think there's a link with performance!

Just go `Debug` > `Delete all breakpoints`

It literally took nearly 10 minutes just to DELETE the breakpoints! 
Significantly faster now, for compiling, scrolling and F12-ing.

Comment: Seems microsoft visual studio goes wrong. everything in visual studio is slow.

Answer (score 3):

I find VS 2010 much more performant - and I have zero issues with my (5200 RPM) harddrive (VS 2008 would often stall when performaning massive R# refactorings (global renaming etc.)).

However, since I have it running a lot longer than VS 2008 ever was able to, it tends to gobble my RAM (700MB+ after 8 hours heavy-duty refactoring on a medium size project).

Trying to include ~7500 images crashed it tho after chewing on for a few minutes (yes, it was a mistake).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS2010 in a VM (2GB RAM, on a 64-bit host with lots of RAM) and it is **slow**.  VS2008 runs blazingly fast, by contrast.

Comment: Probably the same reason for you as for the OP -- VS 2010 uses Direct2D for text, which is much more video driver intensive than GDI.  Hence performance suffers in a VM (actually, what virtualization sw starts to matter a lot, as only a few accelerate Direct3D which Direct2D is based on) and with limited video resources.

Comment: VMware *does* support hardware acceleration, seems pretty in-step to me. VirtualBox has experimental support. Other platforms may not.

Though, I'm interested to see just which VM platform performs better as a dev environment for VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

I have been annoyed with the VS2010 performance for a long time; especially when UNC shares are involved. After I received new hardware and choose to work locally, performance was better, but still slow UI response (despite the fact, that the new hardware counts Intel SSD710, 2 x XEONE5620 and 64GB of RAM).

So I found some performance improvements by excluding the following in your antivirus of choice (mine is Microsoft Security Essentials):

- Added devenv.exe to "Excluded processes"
- Added my projects folder to "Excluded files and locations"

For now this has helped a lot - but there is still tweaks to be done.
Hope others find this helpful.

UPDATED

Also, triggering Tools > Options > Environment > General, and disable the "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" seems to help a little.

Also, do follow this link, [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341281/visual-studio-2010-sp1-performance); **turns out, that Productivity Power Tools (by Microsoft) and ReSharper (by JetBrains) together turn VS2010 into one slow moving giant. Had to disable the former to make the latter play nice**.

Answer (score 1):

Having suffered with poor 2010 performance on several machines for quite a while, I think I've recently found the answer - it just doesn't seem to work well on 32bit versions of windows. I haven't had the opportunity to develop on a 64bit rig until recently and even though that particular machine isn't particularly powerful, it is 64bit and the performance difference in 2010 is very noticeable. 
  On the 64bit machine, inteli-sense isn't a game of roulette that I have to time according to tea breaks; it just works quite nicely!

Answer (score 0):

I have zero performance issues with 2010.

My system has two ATI HD4670 video cards, a raptor hard drive, a 2.8GHz quad processor, and 4GB of ram.  I'm also runing Win7 x64 Ultimate.

Out of curiosity, what are your specs?

One thing you might want to do is review the Remarks on this [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28VS.95%29.aspx).  It notes that you have to have a current driver on XP for hardware acceleration in silverlight to work.

Comment: As a side note, other people on this site have reported issues with VS2010 performance.  Sometimes those issues were resolved simply by getting the latest drivers for their video card installed; others fixed it by buying a current mid-range card.

Answer (score 0):

I had huge performance problems with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. It came to the point that opening a .xaml file took up to a minute. And building was painfully slow. After a lot of research and testing I came to a solution. -> I deleted all files that could be deleted in the folder `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp`. Which was over 40 GB of data. After that Visual Studio was back to normal. I suspect Resharper could have something to do with it. I'm running version 6.1 and it looks like Resharper saves a lot of cache-data in that temp folder.