# why is vs2010 so slow lately? Its nearly unusable

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010

Not sure what has happened on my dev machine but I can barely use visual studio 2010 these days. I have a copy of professional edition installed on a win7 pro x64 build running on top of a i5 M430 and 6 gigs of ram.

With only VS2010 open i've seen the process leak away to 600,000k+.

The editor is extremely slow. Every character I type sends the gui into "Not Responding" for 5 seconds and starting/stopping the debugger is a ~30 second operation.

I've done a repair install. No change.
I've removed productivity power tools and installed the perfwatson extension.

When I installed perfwatson the GUI sped up a bit while opening/loading a project. But the text editor still has an awful delay.

What else can I do? Harware rendering is off in my environment options.

an example of the slowness (literally): typing Height="1024" takes about 30 seconds to display in the text editor and do its update flash to go out of not responding. The word "Height=" takes 5 seconds to show. The intellesense and blank "  " takes another 5 seconds. Each digit pops in every five seconds after that.

Needless to say even trying to edit existing work is a frustrating experience.

edit: rolled back one version on video driver. No noticeable changes after reboot.

**edit: did some winforms projects today. No slow issues with this project type. Must be something with just wpf/sl projects.**

edit 8/18/11: Took troublesome project to the production server. VS2010 editor works great there. Very snappy and responsive. Not at all slow. So it's not something inside my project. It's something in my machine. But a full out OS rebuild is something I can't just do now. Probably will start a bounty soon.

Comment: What other extensions do you have installed?  Have you tried disabling all of them?

Comment: productivity power tools was all I used until I removed it to install perfwatson. It's also worth mentioning I have xceed's wpf datagrid v4 and v4.2 but those aren't "extensions".

Comment: Have you tried disabling Windows Aero?

Comment: This question looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026493/visual-studio-2010-is-it-slow-for-anyone-else

Comment: Kevin, I saw that thread when looking on here for others with my issue. I've turned off hardware rendering and re-launched VS. Seemed okay for a bit but about 10 minutes in I started seeing the interface hang while copying/pasting.

Comment: ...and i've just disabled aero and worked about 15 mins and same deal there too. This is a bad time to squeeze in a rebuild. Hopefully some other answers roll in that will fix this for me.

Comment: This is almost certainly tangential, but does VS still shed most of its memory footprint when you minimize and maximize the window?

Comment: Use PerfWatson and report back to MS http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/05/02/perfwatson.aspx

Comment: Minimized the window. Process went from 524,XXX k down to 510,288k.

Comment: Peter, Perfwatson is installed and WER enabled yet it's never prompted me to send performance data back home and my UI thread has definitely been choking. Any ideas why it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Have you ever enabled debugging with system symbols?  Check Tools: Options: Debugging: Symbols and make sure Microsoft Symbol Servers is unchecked. Empty the symbol cache and delete the cache directory too while you're in there.

Comment: dthorpe, checked the symbols. Weren't enabled but purged cache anyways. Problem persists.

Comment: Your seems to be bigger issue but I am having a bit of issue of my own with VS2010. My compilation is rather slow, I have small project and it takes like 2 minutes to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bios update and a intel chipset update on my machine solved nearly all my performance issues.

The slowness started to creep out into the OS and I was pegging the cpu at idle. I've got 4 cores and 8gb ram. It shouldn't do that.  Now its happy at 8% load at idle.

Thanks to those that tried to help.

Answer (score 9):

Delete the `.sdf` and `.sou` that have the same base file name as your solution file.
If your solution file is

```
c:\MyProject\project.sln
```

You should delete

```
c:\MyProject\project.sdf  
c:\MyProject\project.sou
```

This solves 98% of the problems of slow VS.
These files contain intermediate information that is not important for the functionality of the solution and as time goes by they swell up and become bloated and fragmented. VS relies on these files for and if dealing with them is slow, everything is slow.

Comment: Is it really `.sou` not `.suo`? I can see this in my folder: `[Project name].v11.suo` but not any `*.sou`.

Comment: @TomášZato I believe you are correct, I only have `*.suo` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I have just had an issue where my visual studio project has been working fine for about 2 1/2 years and suddenly every time I clicked run I had to wait about 3 minutes and the same when clicking stop.  I tried the old windows reboot but to no avail.

I found a post about deleting the projects .suo file (it was only 4MB).

I deleted the .suo file and everything is completely back to normal.  I guess the file had corrupted or something.

Answer (score 1):

Having a large number of breakpoints or a large number of files open can cause serious performance problems, but it sounds like your problems are worse than that...

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. not sure what causes this ridiculous performance nightmare, but eventually i had to re-install windows. This same issue was posted on Microsoft forums but the best answer was to re-install VS or windows.